# Is it necessary to implement imagePickerControllerDidCancel?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

While working on a simple app where you open a `Photo Library` then choose an image I faced with a function `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`.

As I understand this function will be performed upon the click on "Cancel" button (while Camera or Photo Lib is open). And inside this func you need to perform `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But i tried not to implement it and the button Cancel was still working as it supposed to.

Is it necessary to use `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` or what is it for ?

Comment: FYI: `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is 
`dismiss(animated:completion:)` in Swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` is optional delegate method of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. If you want to perform some task on the cancel of UIImagePickerController then you can use this method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is from documentation [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerControllerDidCancel:):

> Your delegate’s implementation of this method should dismiss the
> picker view by calling the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: method
> of the parent view controller.
>
> Implementation of this method is optional, but expected.

So it will work fine if you don't implement it (it's optional).

Comment: If you leave it out, just remember, most sample code likes to `present` with `animated: true`, which will leave the UX inconsistent if you cancel.